# Multirow table with variable number of rows

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I'd like to format a table in which first column has a single line of text, centered vertically across a variable number of rows.  Currently, I am using a `IfEqCase` and adding an entry in the first column only if some condition is met.  This works as long as I have a fixed number of rows, and that number is odd (otherwise, the entry will not be vertically centered) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\gridsize}[1]{\ensuremath{#1 \times #1}}

\newcommand{\addrowmpi}[4]{%
\IfEqCase{#1}{%
      {1} {&}  %
      {2} {\gridsize{#2} &}  %
      {4} {&}  %
}
#3 & #4 \%}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Multi-row table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \addrowmpi{1}{512}{462.7}{100} \\
    \addrowmpi{2}{512}{231.4}{50}\\
    \addrowmpi{4}{512}{115.7}{25}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like :

[image]

But I'd like to have a variable number of rows, formatted ideally with something like `addrowmpi`. The first column entry should be centered vertically across the rows.

Is there a way I can use the `multirow` environment with a variable number of rows?

Comment: Welcome! Why not just have a 2 column table with 1 row and then nest a second table in the second cell?

Comment: I'm not really sure what `\addrowmpi` is doing for you. Why not just type the relevant bit on the relevant line? Why specify it for every row in this complex process? I guess I'm not seeing what is motivating this right now as it just seems like an elaborate way of entering `\gridsize{512}` once in one cell of the table.

Comment: well, I've hidden alot of what is going on here.   I wrote a command `addrowmpi` so that I can change what exactly I present in that row. But I left it here because I wanted to know if I could pass this command that formats the rows as an argument to the multirow command.

Comment: The idea of using nested tables may be in fact exactly what I want.  I hadn't thought of this, so thanks!

Comment: The `addrowmpi` is useful because I can rearrange the order in which i present the row entries, do some simple math on the entries to compute the percentages (using the FP package), etc.    So it is useful (although perhaps not so obvious is in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nesting tables I can do essentially what I had in mind.  Here is the code I came up with (simplified somewhat from the above) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newenvironment{timingtable}
{\begin{tabular}{R{30pt}|R{30pt}|R{30pt}}}
{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\addrow}[3]{#1 & #2 &  #3 \%}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}

\begin{document}

% Actual width of each column is 30 + 2*tabcolsep
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Multi-row table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|C{20pt}|@{}p{150pt}@{}|}
    \hline
    512 &
    \begin{timingtable}
    \addrow{462.7}{222.0}{100} \\
    \addrow{231.4}{111.0}{50} \\
    \addrow{154.2}{74.0}{33} \\
    \addrow{115.7}{37.0}{25} \\
    \end{timingtable} \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Multi-row column]

The first column has width 20 + 2*tabcolsep = 40pt, expected.  And each column
in the nested table has width 30+2*tabcolsep = 50.  The `@{}` in the outer tabular command suppresses the additional `tabcolsep` space that would be added around the nested table, making the first and last columns of the nested table too wide.

Comment: I just solved the problem in the original posting and have edited my solution to reflect this, so that it is no longer a query, but an answer.   Thanks.